# Matching items in a document

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to match the following items in square brackets:

```
[O!BOM031][O!BOM016][O!BOM037]
```

My ugly regex is like this:

```
[A-Z!\d\[\]]+
```

It seems to work. However, what I do not know is how to match these items when it is within a document with other text around them.

Example:

```
Rogue's Best Friend [O!BOM030] This wide belt...(text) 
Little Friend Locket [O!BOM031]...(text)
```

I found something that works, but which I know it is totally wrong:

```
([A-Z!\d\[])+\d]
```

For some reason, I can only match in this line: `[O!BOM031][O!BOM016][O!BOM037]`. How do I specify that I only want to match these items in the regex expression and nothing else in the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
\[[A-Z]!BOM\d{3}\]
```

Explanation:

```
\[    // matches [ literally
[A-Z] // matches an uppercase letter
!BOM  // matches !BOM literally
\d{3} // match 3 sequential digits
\]    // matches ] literally
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fS3iD2/1)

Comment: It sure works. So \[ and \]  with \ encloses an expression (meaning, everything else outside is ignored)? What about these two ; ^ $. Doesn't it mean  'Begining of regex'/'End of regex' too (like 'literally')? Or is it completly different perhaps?

Comment: `[` `]` with `\` is literal. Square brackets are character sets in regex. This means that whatever you have in them is what the regex will look for. For example, `[asdf]` will match any of `a`, `s`, `d`, or `f`. There's also negated set `[^asdf]`, which means to match any but what is specified in the set. `^` by itself means beginning of string and `$` means end of string. The meaning of `^` and `$` can change depending on the flags you specify. I'm assuming this is JavaScript. In JS, if you specify the `m` multiline flag, then `^` and `$` matches by line instead of by string. Hope that helps.

Comment: Ah the comments removes my \. I used \ before the `[` and `]` because we want to match those characters literally. This is called escaping the characters. The reason why we do this is because those characters have special meaning in regex.

Comment: Yes, I've just read something similar that I hadn't yet assimilated until now (thanks to you) and that confirms your theory: "You must escape meta characters with a backslash to prevent them being interpreted". This is new to me. Appreciate your explanation.